# Reflection: invoke a method with generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, invoke

I everyone,

I have some issues with invoking a method with reflection.

The method sign is

```
public T Create<T, TK>(TK parent, T newItem, bool updateStatistics = true, bool silent = false)
        where T : class
        where TK : class;
    public T Create<T, TK>(TK parent, string newName, Language language = null, bool updateStatistics = true, bool silent = false)
        where T : class
        where TK : class;
```

I want to use the second overload.

My code is

```
typeof(ObjectType).GetMethod("Create")
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(Item), typeof(TKparent) })
            .Invoke(_objectInstance, new object[] { parent, name, _language, true, false });
```

where Item is a class, TKparent is a type variable and parent is a TKparent instance.

I get a System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException.

I think the problem is related to generics

I tried also this:

```
typeof(ObjectType).GetMethod("Create", new Type[] { typeof(TKparent), typeof(string), typeof(Globalization.Language), typeof(bool), typeof(bool) })
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(Item), typeof(Tparent) })
            .Invoke(_objectInstance, new object[] { parent, name, _language, true, false });
```

but in this case I get a System.NullReferenceException (no method found)

Can anyone help with this, I'm getting mad!

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `GetMethod` finds *multiple* methods with that name before you even tell it which overload you want.  The overload of `GetMethod` that allows you to pass in an array of types works for non-generic methods, but since the parameters are generic you can't use it.

You need to call `GetMethods` and filter down to the one you want:

```
var methods = typeof(ObjectType).GetMethods();

var method = methods.Single(mi => mi.Name=="Create" && mi.GetParameters().Count()==5);

method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(Item), typeof(TKparent) })
      .Invoke(_objectInstance, new object[] { parent, name, _language, true, false });
```

You could obviously inline all of that if you want, but it makes debugging easier if you separate it into separate lines.